# Slow start up - Eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

Our Eclipse e4 application is taking a long time to start up.

I've been profiling it in `VisualVM` and the application takes roughly 30 seconds to load.

The main cause is creating a new logger with `LoggerFactory.getLogger(Example.class)` and initialising the spring context (Does scanning of classes).

Creating the logger takes roughly 10 seconds which is extremely long. I'm wondering if this is to do with lazy loading of bundles where it is blocking until it's loaded.

I've added a `.options` file to show the times taken to load the bundles.

```
8ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309 [0]
38ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309 [0]
Time to load bundles: 23
4ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.3.200.v20181101-1115 [1]
369ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.3.200.v20181101-1115 [1]
368ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.3.200.v20181101-1115"; singleton:="true" [id=1]
369ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.14.0.v20190517-1309"; singleton:="true" [id=0]
2ms to load the activator of org.apache.felix.scr_2.1.14.v20190123-1619 [26]
12ms to load and start the activator of org.apache.felix.scr_2.1.14.v20190123-1619 [26]
12ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.felix.scr"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.1.14.v20190123-1619" [id=26]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.10.400.v20190516-1504 [76]
6ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.10.400.v20190516-1504 [76]
6ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.common"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.400.v20190516-1504"; singleton:="true" [id=76]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.5.100.v20190528-1257 [78]
5ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.5.100.v20190528-1257 [78]
23ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.event"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.5.100.v20190528-1257" [id=78]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.ibm.icu"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="64.2.0.v20190507-1337" [id=6]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.ant.core"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.5.400.v20190510-0606"; singleton:="true" [id=31]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.compare.core"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.6.500.v20190519-2354" [id=32]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.7.300.v20190215-2048"; singleton:="true" [id=34]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.databinding"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.400.v20190513-2118" [id=35]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.v20190510-1100" [id=38]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.expressions"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.6.400.v20190518-1240"; singleton:="true" [id=39]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.400.v20190518-1151"; singleton:="true" [id=40]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.jobs"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.400.v20190506-1457"; singleton:="true" [id=42]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.resources"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.13.400.v20190505-1655"; singleton:="true" [id=43]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.variables"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.4.500.v20190510-0549"; singleton:="true" [id=46]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.draw2d"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.100.201606061308" [id=47]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.8.100.v20190518-1217" [id=49]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.200.v20190506-1457" [id=50]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.15.300.v20190213-1308"; singleton:="true" [id=52]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.7.200.v20190506-1457 [50]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.200.v20190506-1457" [id=50]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier_0.15.300.v20190506-1457 [53]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.15.300.v20190506-1457" [id=53]
19ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.15.300.v20190506-1457" [id=53]
2ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.1.400.v20181215-2145"; singleton:="true" [id=54]
1ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.tools.services"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.8.200.v20181022-1512" [id=56]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.12.500.v20190510-1100"; singleton:="true" [id=57]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.13.500.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=59]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.12.300.v20190510-1100"; singleton:="true" [id=60]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.600.v20190510-1100" [id=61]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.1.400.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=62]
1ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.3.500.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=63]
2ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.10.0.v20190529-1505"; singleton:="true" [id=65]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.3.500.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=66]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.14.700.v20190517-1525"; singleton:="true" [id=67]
1ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.14.600.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=68]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.emf.common"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.16.0.v20190528-0845"; singleton:="true" [id=70]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.18.0.v20190528-0845"; singleton:="true" [id=71]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.14.0.v20190528-0725"; singleton:="true" [id=72]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.16.0.v20190528-0725"; singleton:="true" [id=73]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.app"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.4.200.v20190516-1504"; singleton:="true" [id=74]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.bidi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.0.v20190514-1046"; singleton:="true" [id=75]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.7.400.v20190516-1504"; singleton:="true" [id=81]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.8.400.v20190516-1504"; singleton:="true" [id=83]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.util"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.1.200.v20181008-1820" [id=86]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.help"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.8.400.v20190423-0921"; singleton:="true" [id=89]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.team.core"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.8.600.v20190519-2354"; singleton:="true" [id=103]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.ui"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.113.0.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=105]
1ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.115.0.v20190521-1602"; singleton:="true" [id=106]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.8.400.v20190516-1504 [83]
154ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.8.400.v20190516-1504 [83]
154ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.8.400.v20190516-1504"; singleton:="true" [id=83]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.7.400.v20190516-1504 [81]
19ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.7.400.v20190516-1504 [81]
19ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.7.400.v20190516-1504"; singleton:="true" [id=81]
175ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.15.300.v20190508-0543 [45]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.7.300.v20190215-2048 [34]
3ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.7.300.v20190215-2048 [34]
3ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.7.300.v20190215-2048"; singleton:="true" [id=34]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.10.400.v20190506-1457 [42]
20ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.10.400.v20190506-1457 [42]
21ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.jobs"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.400.v20190506-1457"; singleton:="true" [id=42]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.4.200.v20190516-1504 [74]
10ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.4.200.v20190516-1504 [74]
10ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.app"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.4.200.v20190516-1504"; singleton:="true" [id=74]
218ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.15.300.v20190508-0543 [45]
218ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.runtime"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.15.300.v20190508-0543"; singleton:="true" [id=45]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.3.300.v20190516-1504 [77]
1ms to load the activator of org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_1.1.0.v20180713-1646 [24]
9ms to load and start the activator of org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_1.1.0.v20180713-1646 [24]
10ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.1.0.v20180713-1646" [id=24]
1ms to load the activator of org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_1.1.0.v20180713-1646 [25]
8ms to load and start the activator of org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_1.1.0.v20180713-1646 [25]
8ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.felix.gogo.shell"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.1.0.v20180713-1646" [id=25]
0ms to load the activator of org.apache.felix.gogo.command_1.0.2.v20170914-1324 [23]
4ms to load and start the activator of org.apache.felix.gogo.command_1.0.2.v20170914-1324 [23]
4ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.felix.gogo.command"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.0.2.v20170914-1324" [id=23]
34ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.3.300.v20190516-1504 [77]
33ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.equinox.console"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.3.300.v20190516-1504" [id=77]
Starting application: 1090
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.14.600.v20190513-2118 [68]
2ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.14.600.v20190513-2118 [68]
2ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.14.600.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=68]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench_2.1.400.v20190513-2118 [62]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.1.400.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=62]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.core.services_2.1.400.v20181215-2145 [54]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.1.400.v20181215-2145"; singleton:="true" [id=54]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.10.0.v20190529-1505 [65]
3ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.10.0.v20190529-1505 [65]
2ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.10.0.v20190529-1505"; singleton:="true" [id=65]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_1.8.100.v20190518-1217 [49]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.8.100.v20190518-1217" [id=49]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_1.3.500.v20190513-2118 [63]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.3.500.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=63]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.tools.services_4.8.200.v20181022-1512 [56]
1ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.e4.tools.services_4.8.200.v20181022-1512 [56]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.tools.services"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.8.200.v20181022-1512" [id=56]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.di_1.2.600.v20190510-1100 [61]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.600.v20190510-1100" [id=61]
0ms to load the activator of com.ibm.icu_64.2.0.v20190507-1337 [6]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.ibm.icu"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="64.2.0.v20190507-1337" [id=6]
57ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.emf.common_2.16.0.v20190528-0845 [70]
57ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.emf.common_2.16.0.v20190528-0845 [70]
57ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.emf.common"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.16.0.v20190528-0845"; singleton:="true" [id=70]
2ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.18.0.v20190528-0845 [71]
20ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.18.0.v20190528-0845 [71]
19ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.18.0.v20190528-0845"; singleton:="true" [id=71]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.16.0.v20190528-0725 [73]
1ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.16.0.v20190528-0725 [73]
1ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.16.0.v20190528-0725"; singleton:="true" [id=73]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://3.fwk1318822808:154/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://3.fwk1318822808:331/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.core.resources_3.13.400.v20190505-1655 [43]
105ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.core.resources_3.13.400.v20190505-1655 [43]
104ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.resources"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.13.400.v20190505-1655"; singleton:="true" [id=43]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.core.filesystem_1.7.400.v20190518-1151 [40]
1ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.core.filesystem_1.7.400.v20190518-1151 [40]
1ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.400.v20190518-1151"; singleton:="true" [id=40]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt_1.3.500.v20190513-2118 [66]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.3.500.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=66]
5ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.115.0.v20190521-1602 [106]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.ui_3.113.0.v20190513-2118 [105]
2ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.ui_3.113.0.v20190513-2118 [105]
2ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.ui"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.113.0.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=105]
21ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.115.0.v20190521-1602 [106]
20ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.115.0.v20190521-1602"; singleton:="true" [id=106]
1ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.6.400.v20190518-1240 [39]
1ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.6.400.v20190518-1240 [39]
1ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.expressions"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.6.400.v20190518-1240"; singleton:="true" [id=39]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.14.700.v20190517-1525 [67]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.14.700.v20190517-1525"; singleton:="true" [id=67]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings_0.12.500.v20190510-1100 [57]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.12.500.v20190510-1100"; singleton:="true" [id=57]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions_0.15.300.v20190213-1308 [52]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.15.300.v20190213-1308"; singleton:="true" [id=52]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.12.300.v20190510-1100 [60]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.12.300.v20190510-1100"; singleton:="true" [id=60]
0ms to load the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.13.500.v20190513-2118 [59]
0ms to load and start the activator of org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.13.500.v20190513-2118 [59]
0ms for total start time of osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.13.500.v20190513-2118"; singleton:="true" [id=59]
Application started in : 38177ms
```

What could be causing this?

**Configurations**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First time is normal to take a minute, after that the application should start in a few seconds.

Please let me see your plugins and the configuration of your plugin to review.

Comment: We're having it that every time it is executed it has this wait time trying to create the logger etc. I'll update the question with more information on the configuration.

Comment: Which information exactly would you like for the plugins? I'm not 100% sure which bits will be most useful for you.

Comment: Well, you have a multiple SLF4J binding say in the log you shared, but I see the time loading of every component it is a litle normal. I have two projects with around 30 plugins and it takes around 10 to 15 seconds to start in Windows 10.